# Is it normal to have this many new users join the site all at once?

Tags: discussion

We had a gazillion first posts by new users in the last day or two--unfortunately many of these posts were of lower-quality. Is it normal to have a large influx of new users all at once? Any reason to be concerned?

I'll keep sending them welcome messages for now and hope they aren't robots.

Comment: It's a bit unusual for this site, if it is all legitimate activity it would be interesting to know where they're all coming from.

Comment: This site has been getting lots of new users for a long time, so I haven't noticed it being very different recently. Maybe it is a little more than before? Either way, keep flagging bad posts and we'll take care of it.

Comment: On review, the site stats are fairly typical - we're just past the slump in activity that tends to happen around Dec-Jan though, that might be all it is. Appreciate all the hard work everybody does keeping those review queues down, do feel free to flag anything if you think it's suspicious in any way.

Comment: Generally, it seems to be an uptick in interest for the site, which has received brief mention in the past. The lower-quality posts are expected with new users, which is expected when the site is gaining popularity. It's a sign of healthy growth and is good to notice.

Comment: Could you join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library)?

Comment: @JesseSteele sorry I missed you (the difficulty with being on opposite sides of the earth)

Comment: @JesseSteele you wanted to chat? I'm unable (at the moment) to post in the library, says it's frozen

Comment: @HoldToTheRod try now

Comment: @JesseSteele still frozen =(

Comment: @HoldToTheRod I found the button!